# How to include Windows.Devices.HumanInterfaceDevice.dll in Visual Studio 2017 project

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I want to use the [HID Device class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.humaninterfacedevice.hiddevice) in a C# project in Visual Studio

I'm trying to add the dll to the references buy right clicking the reference section in the solution explorer > Add reference, and browsing to the reference location (C:/Windows/System32/Windows.Devices.HumanInterfaceDevice.dll). I get an error asking if I have the right permissions for the file, or if its a valid COM Assembly.

How should I correctly import this dll?

Answer (score 2):

The class you have referenced here is a UWP class. It will automatically show up in your project if you have a UWP project, but I suspect that you are not working on a UWP project.

Here is an example of the use of the Hid Device Class in a wrapper library:
https://github.com/MelbourneDeveloper/Device.Net/blob/master/src/Hid.Net.UWP/UWPHidDevice.cs . Note that if you want to use Hid with UWP, you need to define your devices in the package manifest. See [here](https://github.com/MelbourneDeveloper/Device.Net/wiki/Device-Permission-Setup).

However, if you are not using UWP - for example, .NET core, you will need to use a different class or library to access Hid devices. Here is a classes for wrapping Windows API

Code: https://github.com/MelbourneDeveloper/Device.Net/blob/master/src/Hid.Net/Windows/HidAPICalls.cs

```
public static class HidAPICalls
    {
        #region Private Static Fields
        private static Guid? _HidGuid;
        #endregion

        #region Constants
        private const int HIDP_STATUS_SUCCESS = 0x110000;
        #endregion

        #region API Calls

        [DllImport("hid.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern bool HidD_GetPreparsedData(SafeFileHandle hidDeviceObject, out IntPtr pointerToPreparsedData);

        [DllImport("hid.dll", SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        private static extern bool HidD_GetManufacturerString(SafeFileHandle hidDeviceObject, IntPtr pointerToBuffer, uint bufferLength);

        [DllImport("hid.dll", SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        private static extern bool HidD_GetProductString(SafeFileHandle hidDeviceObject, IntPtr pointerToBuffer, uint bufferLength);

        [DllImport("hid.dll", SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        private static extern bool HidD_GetSerialNumberString(SafeFileHandle hidDeviceObject, IntPtr pointerToBuffer, uint bufferLength);

        [DllImport("hid.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern int HidP_GetCaps(IntPtr pointerToPreparsedData, out HidCollectionCapabilities hidCollectionCapabilities);

        [DllImport("hid.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern bool HidD_GetAttributes(SafeFileHandle hidDeviceObject, out HidAttributes attributes);

        [DllImport("hid.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern void HidD_GetHidGuid(out Guid hidGuid);

        [DllImport("hid.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern bool HidD_FreePreparsedData(ref IntPtr pointerToPreparsedData);

        private delegate bool GetString(SafeFileHandle hidDeviceObject, IntPtr pointerToBuffer, uint bufferLength);

        #endregion

        #region Private Static Methods
        private static string GetHidString(SafeFileHandle safeFileHandle, GetString getString)
        {
            var pointerToBuffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(126);
            var isSuccess = getString(safeFileHandle, pointerToBuffer, 126);
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pointerToBuffer);
            WindowsDeviceBase.HandleError(isSuccess, "Could not get Hid string");
            return Marshal.PtrToStringUni(pointerToBuffer);
        }
        #endregion

        #region Public Static Methods
        public static HidAttributes GetHidAttributes(SafeFileHandle safeFileHandle)
        {
            var isSuccess = HidD_GetAttributes(safeFileHandle, out var hidAttributes);
            WindowsDeviceBase.HandleError(isSuccess, "Could not get Hid Attributes");
            return hidAttributes;
        }

        public static HidCollectionCapabilities GetHidCapabilities(SafeFileHandle readSafeFileHandle)
        {
            var isSuccess = HidD_GetPreparsedData(readSafeFileHandle, out var pointerToPreParsedData);
            WindowsDeviceBase.HandleError(isSuccess, "Could not get pre parsed data");

            var result = HidP_GetCaps(pointerToPreParsedData, out var hidCollectionCapabilities);
            if (result != HIDP_STATUS_SUCCESS)
            {
                throw new Exception($"Could not get Hid capabilities. Return code: {result}");
            }

            isSuccess = HidD_FreePreparsedData(ref pointerToPreParsedData);
            WindowsDeviceBase.HandleError(isSuccess, "Could not release handle for getting Hid capabilities");

            return hidCollectionCapabilities;
        }

        public static string GetManufacturer(SafeFileHandle safeFileHandle)
        {
            return GetHidString(safeFileHandle, HidD_GetManufacturerString);
        }

        public static string GetProduct(SafeFileHandle safeFileHandle)
        {
            return GetHidString(safeFileHandle, HidD_GetProductString);
        }

        public static string GetSerialNumber(SafeFileHandle safeFileHandle)
        {
            return GetHidString(safeFileHandle, HidD_GetSerialNumberString);
        }

        public static Guid GetHidGuid()
        {
            if (_HidGuid.HasValue)
            {
                return _HidGuid.Value;
            }

            HidD_GetHidGuid(out var hidGuid);

            _HidGuid = hidGuid;

            return hidGuid;
        }
        #endregion
}
```

The above is a part of the [Device.Net](https://github.com/MelbourneDeveloper/Device.Net) library which would allow you to use Hid across multiple platforms.